# If {$x_1,...,x_k$} is independent and $y$ is not in span{$x_1,...,x_k$}, how to show that {$x_1,...,x_k,y$} is independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

Since $y$ cannot possibly be linear combination of span x, so {$x_1,...,x_k,y$} is certainly independent. But I don't know how to explain in formal language, could someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $a_1 x_1 + \cdots + a_k x_k + a y = 0$. We need to show that $a_1 = \cdots = a_k = a = 0$.

If $a = 0$, then we have a linear combination $a_1 x_1 + \cdots + a_k x_k = 0$, so since $\{x_1, \ldots, x_k\}$ is linearly independent, we have $a_1 = \cdots = a_k = 0$, and we are done.

If $a \neq 0$, then
$$
y = -\frac{a_1}{a} x_1 - \cdots - \frac{a_k}{a} x_k,
$$
but this contradicts the assumption that $y \notin \operatorname{span}\{x_1,\ldots, x_k\}$.

Therefore, it is necessarily the case that $a_1 = \cdots = a_k = a = 0$, so $\{x_1, \ldots, x_k, y\}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: Nice answer thanks

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $a_1x_1+...+a_kx_k+by=0.$ Then $a_1x_1+...+a_kx_k=-by.$ Since $y$ is not in the span of $\{x_1,...,x_k\},$ $b=0.$ Then because $\{x_1,...,x_k\}$ are linearly independent $a_1=a_2=...=a_k=0.$ Thus $\{x_1,...,x_k,y\}$ is independent.